# Pass all Meteor users to Apollo context

Tags: reactjs, meteor, apollo, apollo-client

It is possible to pass the current user to the context using [ApolloLink](https://github.com/apollographql/meteor-integration/issues/109). But is it possible to do the same for a list of all users? 
I would like to pass all the users in my application to the context (if possible) so I can access it through context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The `context` arg can be an async function that fetches anything from the database you want:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server.html#constructor-options-lt-ApolloServer-gt

Comment: This is true. But I realized it overrides anything passed using `ApolloClient`. In my Meteor app, I'm using `ApolloClient` to pass the logged in user to the context. If I define a custom context in `createApolloServer`, the user defined in `ApolloClient` is no more available. A solution would have been to just define the current user in the context, but I also founded out that using this.userId or Meteor.userId() in `createApolloServer` all return undefine.

Comment: You might find it helpful to update to the new version (3.*) of `meteor/apollo`, which has a different API: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/meteor.html#Server